# When to use `silent` code analysis severity?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

Analyzer feedback severity levels are [explained in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#rule-severity). But in my eyes  `silent` and `none` severity levels seem both to have the same meaning - "I don't want this rule checked for":

For `none`:

> Suppressed completely.

For `silent`:

> Non-visible to user.  The diagnostic is reported to the IDE diagnostic engine, however.

**What exactly is the effect of "reporting to IDE" for VS2019 and in what scenarios should one prefer `silent` over `none`?**

Comment: was just wondering the same myself; I see no replies but did you find any information outside of stackoverflow?

Comment: @ChristopherKing Nothing. wrote my take as answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think `silent` shows up in the editor as the "three dots" or ghosted text, while `none` doesn't show up. I might recall this not behaving consistently in the past, but it seems to happen in Visual Studio 16.10.0. I like [Imre's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560087/316760).

[image]

It seems like:

- `suggestion`, `error`, and `warning` show up in the editor and Error List.
- `silent` shows up only in the editor.
- `none` shows up in neither.

Comment: Interesting.. that is, contrary to the quoted definition in OP, "silent" is visible to the user;)´´. Go figure.

Comment: Exactly. I think they meant "non-visible in the Error List". It seems that `suggestion`/`error`/`warning` show up in the editor and Error List; `silent` shows up only in the editor; and `none` shows up nowhere. The error list is sometimes out of date, so I'm not totally sure.

Comment: I don't get the three dots in silent :(

Comment: This actually makes sense for `silent`: "The diagnostic is reported to the IDE diagnostic engine", meaning that you see the `...` in the IDE, but not in the `Error List`. It's just not obvious at first what `IDE diagnostic engine` means.

Comment: See ['Hidden' severity versus 'None' severity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers#hidden-severity-versus-none-severity), which corresponds to `silent` vs `none`.

Comment: @kofifus I also don't get the "3 dots" in silent.  It's a bit of a shame, actually.  I do have certain things I consider so unimportant I don't want them cluttering up the Information message list, but I wouldn't mind the 3 dots staying!

Comment: With your description, then what's the difference between `silent` and `suggestion`? I've never seen suggestions showing up in the errors list.

Comment: @ygoe Looks like my suggestions are green squiggles, and are in Error List. Are the Error/Warning/Message toggle buttons enabled in your Error List?

Comment: @Vimes I don't have such a project at hand now. Green squiggles have always been warnings for me, suggestions had the three grey dots.

Comment: @yogue When I filter on `suggestion`, it affects the green squiggles and not the dots.

Answer (score 8):

The distinction is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#hidden-severity-versus-none-severity):

> `Hidden` (silent) severity rules that are enabled by default differ from disabled or `None` severity rules in certain aspects.
>
> - If any code fix is registered for a `Hidden` severity rule, Visual Studio offers the fix as a light bulb code-refactoring action even if the hidden diagnostic isn't visible to the user. The fix isn't offered if the severity rule is disabled as `None`.
> - `Hidden` severity rules can be bulk configured by entries that set rule severity of multiple analyzer rules at once in an EditorConfig file. `None` severity rules can’t be configured this way. Instead, they must be configured through entries that set rule severity in an EditorConfig file for each rule ID.

Comment: Sounds more plausible than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Due to lack of better information and until proven wrong, I'm considering them equal for practical effect.

Still, considering this as an opportunity to define a useful semantic difference, I would suggest to:

- **USE** `none` when you object to given rule in chosen scope. This rule is not mandatory to be followed.
- **USE** `silent` for rules which must be followed, but are causing too much noise and are suppressed temporarily while still communicating the desired target state.